# Api Rest .Net Core [VS 2019] : no devuelve todos los objetos

Tags: c#

Tenemos una API en .Net Core (C#) que debe devolver el siguiente objeto

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Get()
{
   Estudiante resp = new Estudiante();
   resp.id     = "00";
   resp.nombre = "nombre";
   
   resp.est = new DatoEstudiante();
   resp.est.ciudad = "gye";
   resp.est.region = "costa";
   
   return Ok(resp);
}
```

Al ejecutar *Get*, no devuelve la info de la clase `DatoEstudiante`.

**Respuesta del Get**

```
{
  "id" : "00",
  "nombre" : "nombre"
}
```

Por favor nos pueden ayudar con este problema?

**Clases Utilizadas**

```
public class Estudiante()
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string nombre {get; set;}

    DatoEstudiante est = new DatoEstudiante;
}

public class DatoEstudiante()
{
   public string ciudad {get;set;}
   public string regios {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar propiedades y no instancias. De esta forma actualiza tu modelo:

```
public class Estudiante()
    {
        public string id {get;set;}
        public string nombre {get; set;}
    
        public DatoEstudiante est {get; set;}
    }
    
    public class DatoEstudiante()
    {
       public string ciudad {get;set;}
       public string regios {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero fue un error de tipeo la declaración de DatoEstudiante